# Google AR-Core in custom device

Tags: android, arguments, arcore

I am developing a custom android device, and I wanted to ask about the possibilities of using arcore.

I am an indie developer so google accept my prototype on "Google Play Services", I don't think it is an option. But I know that there are other projects like Tango, that use arcore.

I also wanted to ask, if the depthmap of ar core would take advantage of the two cameras of the device since I have two identical cameras

Comment: Well in the release notes for 1.22 they said "Support for stereo camera depth is expected to become available in ARCore SDK 1.23.0." but there was no mention of it in the release notes for 1.23

Comment: Yes, there is a request on github with no responder about it.

Comment: Yeah, to me its a sign they may chase after lidar like Apple, so I'm not going to waste money buying a dual camera device...

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to follow their device certification program to get your device certified.

They confirm this here and mention the Google AR OEM Portal: [https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/device-certification]]](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/device-certification%5D%5D)

Unfortunately, at the time of writing there is no link to the portal so I think their enterprise partner program is probably the best place to look: https://www.android.com/enterprise/partners/

For your purposes if this is a small independent application you may find it easier to simply build on an existing commercial device that meets your requirements.